# Prevent diagonal scroll in nested flipview

Tags: scroll, uwp, diagonal, flipview

The code looks like this:

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <Grid Height="400" Background="Blue"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <FlipView x:Name="DigestFlipView" Style="{StaticResource DigestViewStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

And then in my DigestViewStype I have made it vertical as follows:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
<Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

What I want is, when swipe is vertical, only inner FlipView should kick in. Also, when swipe is horizontal, only outer FlipView should kick in.

I get the desired behavior if I replace inner FlipView with a ListView. ListView scrolls for vertical swipes and FlipView for horizontal ones. I have tried playing with templates with no luck. Is there a way to achieve what I need with FlipViews?

Comment: Have you tried to change the "ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" attached property to Disabled for the inner FlipView and "ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" to Enabled for it?

Comment: @JulienShepherd : thanx, tried the same, but result is same. It's scrolling diagonally.